# C# code, which creates "Formatted" PowerPoint slides

Tags: c#, powerpoint, interop

I'm creating a small program that automatically creates already "formatted" slides I can't apply the logo to the master slide, to replicate it every time I click on create new slide on PowerPoint.

I am using `Microsoft.Core.Interop.PowerPoint`.

This is my code:

```
string logo = @"C:...\Desktop\Logo_base.png";

string[] pwPnt = {
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, " 
        
Application pwPntApplicazione = new Application();
        
Presentation pwPtnPresentazione = pwPntApplicazione.Presentations.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
        
string themeName = @"D:...\tf16401370.pptx";
                
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Master master;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides slides;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Slide slide;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextRange objText;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout =
    pwPtnPresentazione.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];
       
slides = pwPtnPresentazione.Slides;
slide = slides.AddSlide(1, customLayout);
slide.FollowMasterBackground = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
slide.ApplyTemplate(themeName);
        
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape = slide.Shapes[2];
slide.Shapes.AddPicture(logo, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, shape.Left = -0, shape.Top = -1, shape.Width = 100, shape.Height = 30);

objText = slide.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange;
objText.Text = "TITOLO";
//objText.Text = $"TITOLO {i + 1}";
objText.Font.Name = "Arial";
objText.Font.Size = 42;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shp;
shp = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left: 400, Top: 110, Width: 450, Height: 450);

//shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = $"{pwPnt[i]}";
shp.TextEffect.FontName = "Arial";
shp.TextEffect.FontSize = 26;
shp.TextEffect.Alignment = MsoTextEffectAlignment.msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered;
        
pwPtnPresentazione.SaveAs(C:..Slide.pptx",
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault,
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

Comment: So your problem is that you want the slides to have the background of the master slide and this does not work?
If so try setting
    slide.FollowMasterBackground = MsoTriState.msoTrue;

Comment: Not really, I set a default theme, the slides take it, but during the presentation then with PowerPoint running, if I click on a new slide the logo that I try to insert disappears. 
So I would like to "add" the logo to the template so as not to lose it if the user creates a new slide.

Comment: I did it, thanks @MarkWittmann, sorry for my imperfect english. This is the working code:
`code`
...                pwPtnPresentazione.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];
            pwPtnPresentazione.SlideMaster.Shapes.AddPicture(logo, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, 0, 0, 100, 25);
...
`

Comment: Great! Other user might have that problem too so if you want you can post this as an answer and not only a comment.

You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so.

Answer (score 0):

How I write in my comment, this is the code for the solution of my problem:

```
...
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides slides;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Slide slide;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextRange objText;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout =
                pwPtnPresentazione.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];
            pwPtnPresentazione.SlideMaster.Shapes.AddPicture(logo, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, 0, 0, 100, 25);
            pwPtnPresentazione.SlideMaster.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left: 400, Top: 110, Width: 450, Height: 450);
...
```

Add this at the code present in my question, after the creation of Presentation.

Practically, I have added on all presentation a modify at the shape of the MasterSlide